# Действительная продолжительность видео и аудио файлов

Tags: c#, аудио, видео, ffmpeg

В данный момент я работаю над приложением, которое позволяет записывать видео файлы. Параллельно с видео файлом записывается аудио файл. В итоге получается 2 файла: .mp4 и .wav.

Моей задачей является объединение этих двух файлов. Для того, чтобы объединить видео и аудио файлы, файлы должны быть приблизительно одной продолжительности. Для того, чтобы определить, являются ли видео и аудио файлы одинаковыми по продолжительности, я провела ряд опытов. Для этого я записывала видео ролики: 5 раз по 15 минут, 5 раз по 30 минут, 5 раз по 45 минут и 5 раз по 60 минут.

В ходе опытов я фиксировала следующие значения:

1. Время создания файлов (с точностью до мс).

   IDateTime videoCreated = _fileWrapper.GetCreationTime(videoPath);

   IDateTime audioCreated = _fileWrapper.GetCreationTime(audioPath);
2. Время последнего изменения файлов (с точностью до мс).

   IDateTime videoModified = _fileWrapper.GetLastWriteTime(videoPath);

   IDateTime audioModified = _fileWrapper.GetLastWriteTime(audioPath);
3. Измеряла продолжительность файлов с помощью ffprobe.
4. Я также высчитывала продолжительнось файлов, отнимая от времени последнего изменения время создания файла. Назовем эту величину вычисленной продолжительностью.

Далее я опишу результаты, которые я получила.

Если мы возьмем во внимание вычисленную продолжительность, то видео и аудио файлы приблизительно одинаковы. Аудио файлы немного короче видео файлов (в среднем 0,415 с, что несущественно).

Перейдем к продолжительности по ffprobe. Аудио файлы существенно длиннее видео файлов. Далее представлена средняя разница аудио и видео файлов по группам:

```
15 мин -12,426 с;
30 мин -16,942 с;
45 мин -31,403 с;
60 мин -34,702 с.
```

Результаты только для аудио файлов:

Продолжительность по ffprobe несколько меньше, чем вычисленная продолжительность. Ниже представлена средняя разница в разных группах:

```
15 мин -0,424 с;
30 мин -1,129 с;
45 мин -1,816 с;
60 мин -2,292 с.
```

Результаты только для видео файлов:

Продолжительность по ffprobe существенно меньше, чем вычисленная продолжительность. Результаты по группам:

```
15 мин -13,171 с;
30 мин -18,630 с;
45 мин -33,666 с;
15 мин -37,326 с.
```

Почему продолжительность по ffprobe меньше вычисленной продолжительности? Как объяснить все эти наблюдения? Какова действительная продолжительность файлов?

Дополнения:
Запись видео. Используется библиотека Vlc.DotNet.Core. Имеется класс RecordOnvifVideoCommand. Метод Execute:

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
        {        
            if (_videoRecorder != null && _videoRecorder.IsPlaying())
            {
                _videoRecorder.Stop(); //!!!
                _videoRecorder = null;

                TimeSpan videoRecordingTime = TimeSpan.Zero; OnRecordingStopped?.Invoke(sessionService.CurrentDevice.Device.Id, videoRecordingTime);
                return;
            }
            _videoRecorder = new VlcMediaPlayer(_vlcLibDirectory.DirectoryInfo);

            _filenameGenerator.Folder = sessionService.PatientVideoDirectory;
            _filenameGenerator.GenerateNextFileName();
            string fileName = _filenameGenerator.GetName();

            string fileDestination = Path.Combine(_filenameGenerator.FolderPath, fileName);

            string[] mediaOptions =
            {
                ":sout=#file{dst='" + fileDestination + "'}",
//                ":live-caching=0",// TODO: check what that parameter does!
                ":sout-keep" /*Keep sout open (default disabled) : use the same sout instance across the various playlist items, if possible.*/
//                ":file-logging", ":vvv", ":extraintf=logger", ":logfile=VlcLogs.log"
            };

            _videoRecorder.SetMedia(sessionService.CurrentDevice.MediaStreamUri, mediaOptions); _videoRecorder.Play();

            OnRecordingStarted?.Invoke(fileName);
        }
```

Запись аудио. Используется библиотека NAudio.

```
private void StartRecording()
        {
            try
            {
                string patientFolder = Patient.GetString();
                _waveFileDestination = string.Empty;

                if (IsForVideo)
                {
                    _waveFileDestination = Path.Combine(_systemSetting.VideoServerPath, patientFolder,
                        _videoFileNameGenerator.GetCurrentNameWithExtension("wav"));
                }
                else
                {
                    _audioFileNameGenerator.Folder = Path.Combine(_systemSetting.AudioPath, patientFolder);
                    _audioFileNameGenerator.GenerateNextFileName();
                    _waveFileDestination = Path.Combine(_audioFileNameGenerator.FolderPath,
                        _audioFileNameGenerator.GetName());
                }

                _waveSource = new WaveInEvent
                {
                    DeviceNumber = CapturingDevice.Number,
                    WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1)
                };

                _waveSource.DataAvailable += WaveSourceOnDataAvailable;
                _waveSource.RecordingStopped += WaveSourceOnRecordingStopped;

                _waveFile = new WaveFileWriter(_waveFileDestination, _waveSource.WaveFormat);

                _waveSource.StartRecording();

                if (!IsForVideo)
                {
                    // Save audio media entity
                    _recordingMediaId = Media.AddToLocation(Patient.Id,
                        ExaminationId, _audioFileNameGenerator.GetName(),
                        MediaType.Audio, 0, _workstation.LocationId, DateTime.Now);
                    Media newMedia = Media.Get(_recordingMediaId);

                    MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem(newMedia, _systemSetting, _mediaManager)
                    {
                        PatientSsn = newMedia.AccessionNumber
                    };

                    OnAudioAdded(mediaItem);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }

private void StopRecording()
        {

            try
            {

                _waveSource.StopRecording();

                if (!IsForVideo)
                {
                    Media media = Media.Get(_recordingMediaId);    
                    media.Duration = Duration.Seconds;
                    Media.Update(media);
                    _recordingMediaId = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    IsForVideo = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
            }

            OnStateChanged();
        }
```

Comment: Здесь ошибка, скорее всего, кроется в том, что видео/аудио- файл может создаться, а начало записи произойдет не сразу. Пока не увидим код, как вы осуществляете запись файлов, ничего точного сказать нельзя.
`Как определить, правильно ли определяется продолжительность по ffprobe?` Для этого вам нужно посмотреть в свойствах файла (либо с помощью проигрывателя), сколько длится записанный файл. Ну и от нее уже отталкиваться.